# Change output format of current_timestamp in Snowflake

Tags: r, datetime, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to update timestamp of certain records in snowflake. I want the timestamp to be stored in specific format (`YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` eg - `2021-12-10 10:12:35`) in snowflake. I am doing this through R.

I can do this directly in snowflake but I am not able to do this using R.

In snowflake, I run these two lines to get my data in required format

```
alter session set timestamp_output_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'
UPDATE table SET TIMESTAMP=current_timestamp
```

In R, I am using our internal package `snowflake` to query the data where I do -

```
snowflake::query("alter session set timestamp_output_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'")
snowflake::query("UPDATE table SET TIMESTAMP=current_timestamp")
```

This returns `2021-12-10 10:12:35.349 Z` as time which I think is default format to show time in snowflake. So the 1st `alter session` command has no impact (?).

How can I achieve my expected output using R ?

I think I saw somewhere that I can do `current_timestamp.format(...)` or something similar to change the format of `current_timestamp` but I can't find it now.

Comment: The output format you have there contains a timezone, therefore the [Z](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-datetime.html#timestamp-ltz-timestamp-ntz-timestamp-tz). Have you tried with **alter session set TIMESTAMP_NTZ_OUTPUT_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';** ?

Comment: @Sergiu Tried that, no change. I was trying to include both the commands in single command like this `snowflake::query(alter session...;UPDATE table....)` but unfortunately, `snowflake::query` accepts only one command at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Dates and timestamps are stored in databases as numbers, there is no way to define a format that they are stored in - as that would make no sense with a number.

The format that a date/timestamp is displayed in is set by the application being used to query the data

Comment: OK then I don't mind saving the time as string (varchar). My question would then be how to change the current time (`current_timestamp`) to string which has the format that I am looking for. Thank you for your input/answer.

Comment: Storing data as the “wrong” datatype is a really bad idea. What is stopping you displaying the date in the format you want?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how this works in R; maybe your `"snowflake::query("..."` statements each open a new session, so changing the format sesson-wide in the first one doesn't affect the second? Or maybe you've created some kind of persistent snowflake-session object in R earlier in your code, then of course it should take effect. But either way, if you want to make sure any SQL RDBMS returns query results in a specific format, put that directly in the query itself. Something like this:

```
snowflake::query("UPDATE table SET TIMESTAMP=current_timestamp")
snowflake::query("SELECT TO_STRING(TIMESTAMP, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') FROM TABLE)
```

And you'll see that your timestamps **are** stored "in the correct format". That is because, as others have tried to explain above, they aren't actually stored "with a format" at all: A timestamp *doesn't have* any intrinsic format. Formats are something that is applied only on *displaying* values.